# How to change the Cucumber Scenario result into the @After hook

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I want to change the scenario status for known issues into the After hook. 
Something like:

```
@After
public void afterScenario(Scenario scenario) {
   if(scenario.isFailed() && scenario.getSourceTagNames().contains("knownIssue")){
        //scenario.add(Result.SKIPPED)
   }
}
```

The idea is tests, which fail because of known bug to be skipped into the test report.

Thanks,
Nayden

Comment: May I know how did you achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate the scenario with `@KnownIssue` and then run cucumber with `--tags "not @KnownIssue"` or its `@CucumberOptions` equivalent.

Comment: That's a good solution, but it will prevent the execution of these tests at all. I was thinking to execute the test and only in case of failure to just change the status to that test to different than Failed. The idea is to include them into the test report, but with different status and color.

Comment: You can also configure a second job/step/thingy in your build system that runs only the tests the known issues. You'll have to monitor your known issues anyway.

Comment: If you are going to monitor your known issues. Check out the `--wip` flag. It will fail the build when there are any passing issues.

Answer (score 0):

it is your test execution engine that is responsible for this aspect, aka TestNG, JUnit. 
So the question is: How to change Test Execution Status Programmatically? [Here](https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/TT/testNG+-+changing+test+results+dynamically) is one explained. You can hook in to the Test Execution Engine either by the way explained in the artcicle or from your method - what is important - you have to work with the Test Execution Engine and not Cucumber.

Answer (score 0):

[Gherkin with qaf](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) supports what you are looking for. With qaf

- you can achieve it by test ng after method invocation listener.
- In addition you also can add meta-data at step level and handle it in `onFailure` method of [step listener](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_listeners.html#teststep-listener) to modify exception to Skip exception depending on step meta data. Which automatically skips tests where that step is called and failed.